# jquery replace a digit of a number

Tags: jquery, replace, numbers, digits

I would like to replace a digit in a number (the third, for example), but that replaces the first. Why ?

```
var x = "1111";
var x = x.replace(x[2],"2");
// output : 2111,
// but I would have liked : 1121
```

Comment: The problem is because `x[2]` returns `1`, and `replace()` only works on the first instance it finds - the first `1` in the string in this case. You need to explicitly chop up the string using `subtr()` and concatenating the changes. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: Understood !.... Thanks.